# Amazon S3 access from Cloudfront through HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

- I have a S3 bucket, serving as static website.
- I have a cloudfront distribution, pointed towards HTTP endpoint of the bucket.
- I want to limit access to my S3 bucket to only Cloudfront.

I guess I can do this by adding Principal: arn:iam:cloudfront ....

But this allows direct S3 access, not HTTP Endpoint access.

When I configure Cloudfront to serve S3 bucket directly, it doesn't show subdirectory index.htmls. In order to reach mysite.com/blog/, I have to type mysite.com/blog/index.html

For this reason, I have to use HTTP endpoint of the S3 as if the site is not on S3 but on an Apache server.

Now I can't restrict access via arn:iam:cloudfront. Because Cloudfront becomes yet another web crawler, S3 becomes yet another web server.

They suggest adding custom headers so that the server understands it's the cloudfront. But S3 doesn't support custom headers.

Restricting user agent to CloudFront and Principal to AWS: * does a brief work but it doesn't stop UserAgent spoofing.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Solved. Full tutorial can be seen here http://tuts.emrealadag.com/post/cloudfront-cdn-for-s3-static-web-hosting/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't configure the origin as S3 at all -- configure it as a Custom origin and then use the bucket's website endpoint hostname as the origin server hostname.

At that point, you should be able to configure an [Origin Custom Header](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html#forward-custom-headers-restrict-access) that CloudFront will send to the origin -- which happens to be the bucket's web site endpoint.

`User-Agent` is not on the [list of custom headers that CloudFront won't forward](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html#forward-custom-headers-blacklist), so you should be able to send a custom user agent string -- acting somewhat like a static password -- in the requests from CloudFront to S3, and configure your bucket to only allow that custom user agent.

It could still theoretically be spoofed, but since it's a random string that you made up, nobody knows that value except you, S3, and CloudFront, and it would be very tricky for someone to spoof an unknown value, particularly since S3 simply denies access, without explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much, setting User-Agent something custom worked!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this method?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

> To ensure that your users access your objects using only CloudFront
>   URLs, regardless of whether the URLs are signed, perform the following
>   tasks:
>
> Create an origin access identity, which is a special CloudFront user,
>   and associate the origin access identity with your distribution. (For
>   web distributions, you associate the origin access identity with
>   origins, so you can secure all or just some of your Amazon S3
>   content.) You can also create an origin access identity and add it to
>   your distribution when you create the distribution.
>
> Change the permissions either on your Amazon S3 bucket or on the
>   objects in your bucket so only the origin access identity has read
>   permission (or read and download permission). When your users access
>   your Amazon S3 objects through CloudFront, the CloudFront origin
>   access identity gets the objects on your users' behalf. If your users
>   request objects directly by using Amazon S3 URLs, they're denied
>   access. The origin access identity has permission to access objects in
>   your Amazon S3 bucket, but users don't.

Comment: Yes, I added Principal - CanonicalUser value as the origin access identity but it didn't work. I guess it didn't work due to reason I mentioned. It would have worked if I connected S3 bucket directly to CloudFront. But I had to connect S3 bucket's URL, not the bucket object (due to subdirectory problem).